# Strange behavior with dir "../*.*" (Note the forward slash)

Tags: cmd, directory

Having the following folder structure:

- A [Dir]
  File.txt

  - B [Dir]

    - C [Dir]

**Current working directory is at C**

If I do

```
DIR "..\File.txt"
```

I get no files and that is expected since B is empty.

However if I do

```
DIR "../File.txt"         --> Note the / instead of the \
```

I get the file at A !!!

If I do

```
DIR "../*.*"
```

I get the file at A and the dir output says the file is at B !!!

Here's the output of the DIR commands:

```
E:\a>dir

 Directory of E:\a                          

2016-09-19  08:20    <DIR>          .         
2016-09-19  08:20    <DIR>          ..        
2016-09-19  08:20                 5 File.txt     
2016-09-19  08:19    <DIR>          b         

E:\a>cd b

E:\a\b>dir

 Directory of E:\a\b

2016-09-19  08:19    <DIR>          .
2016-09-19  08:19    <DIR>          ..
2016-09-19  10:20    <DIR>          c

E:\a\b>cd c

E:\a\b\c>dir

 Directory of E:\a\b\c

2016-09-19  10:20    <DIR>          .
2016-09-19  10:20    <DIR>          ..

E:\a\b\c>dir "..\*.*"                            

 Directory of E:\a\b                             

2016-09-19  08:19    <DIR>          .              
2016-09-19  08:19    <DIR>          ..             
2016-09-19  10:20    <DIR>          c              

E:\a\b\c>dir "../*.*"

 Directory of E:\a\b

2016-09-19  08:20    <DIR>          .
2016-09-19  08:20    <DIR>          ..
2016-09-19  08:20                 5 File.txt
2016-09-19  08:19    <DIR>          b
```

Really strange. Is someone knowing what's happening?

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069). You already asked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1125897/strange-behavior-with-dir-note-the-forward-slash) on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an error in the `dir` tokenizer.

`dir` command will try to resolve the requested path+fileMask to a full directory path and then it will append the file mask (or asume a `*`) to enumerate the files inside the resolved path.

Curiously, the folder resolution has not any problem to determine what the starting folder should be (`Directory of E:\a\b` in your output), BUT the tokenizer has a problem removing the *relative* folder reference from the file mask when forward slashes are used.

The result is that once the folder is resolved to `E:\a\b\` (correct), the full `../*.txt` is appended (wrong part, the relative folder reference should have been separated from the file mask), and then `E:\a\b\../*.txt` is enumerated (that is, `E:\a\*.txt`) without any problem

Now, if we create a deeper hierarchy (`E:\a\b\c\d`), with `d` the current active directory, this behaviour can be tested by replacing the request to `dir "../../*.txt"`. In this case, the starting folder will be resolved to 
`E:\a\b`, but as the `"../../*.txt"` will be appended, at the end the root folder will be enumerated.

**note**: at this moment I don't have a debugger at hand to be 100% secure of this, but it has been tested running a `cmd` instance under `Api Monitor` and the api calls show the described behaviour.